python uv module : confusing behaviour
I started to consider using uv for my project instead for pip. However, so far I am finding using it not as straightforward as I'd hoped.
EDIT: OS Windows 10, Python 3.10 installed from Windows Store.

uv is not added to PATH variable (I did not have this issue in my initial testing, but now I do. Restart does not help)
Confusing behavior with VENV created by uv


once venv created via uv and activated, it does not see uv anymore (which makes sense, but then I can't pip install uv in the new venv, because pip is used from the core python installation.

mkdir uvtest
cd uvtest
python -m uv init
python -m uv venv
.venv\Scripts\activate
python -m uv help REM .venv\Scripts\python.exe: No module named uv
pip install uv REM Requirement already satisfied: uv in c:\users\sergz\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (0.5.13)```


A few things to note:

uv is not a module but an executable. You should not attempt to run it with Python.
While installable via PyPI, uv should instead be installed using its own standalone installer. This installer will do whatever necessary to add uv to PATH.
uv does not need to be installed for each project. It is a global tool.
You don't need to activate environments. Prefer uv idioms, because uv is smart enough to know what to do in a project context.

The workflow should thus look like this:
$ uv init uvtest && cd uvtest
Initialized project `uvtest` at `~\uvtest`

$ uv venv
Using CPython 3.13.0
Creating virtual environment at: .venv
Activate with: .venv\Scripts\activate

# https://docs.astral.sh/uv/concepts/projects/dependencies/
$ uv add some-dependency
Resolved 1 packages in 3.14ms
Prepared 1 package in 6.28ms
Installed 1 package in 2.72ms
 + some-dependency==1.2.3

# https://docs.astral.sh/uv/concepts/projects/run/
$ uv run some-tool --version
4.5.6


Also, you might as well uninstall your Python installation from Windows Store and let uv manage that for you (uv python install 3.10).

At work we install Python from Windows Company portal. I’d expect any large enterprise won’t allow custom installation (at least for now)
